Do we really want a [debunk] tag?
During an edit I removed a newly-hatched debunk tag from Is it true that “ Shower meteors always come in spurts separated by spells of inactivity that can last up to a few minutes” Since the OP put it back again and I don't want to get into an edit war, let's think about it here in meta, where there is a rich tradition of discussing the pros and cons of new tags.
The probem I see with a specific tag about "debunking" is that it opens up a whole category of low quality questions, where any suboptimal wording, like "always" instead of "often seems to" is the source of another question with little or no long-term value.
Now I have probably asked a few "debunk" questions myself in each SE site, for example here in Astronomy SE:

Why are these objects moving at Vastly Different Speeds along the same orbit?
Orbital velocity of a planet - why is my calculation off by about 10%?

One led to the fixing of a bug in a website, another led to the correction of a paper between preprint and publication.
And in related SE sites:

Are there measurements or calculations that suggest atmospheric ice plates would be horizontal to within 0.1 degrees?
How could the recently explained "glints" seen by DSCOVR appear so compact considering the finite size of the sun?
Now what do we think? Is this purple dot really caused by Cassegrain optics and coherent backscattering?
Are there ANY verified satellite images of visible light coherent backscattering from Earth?
Did New Horizons use its smaller medium-gain antenna for most/all downlinking of Pluto and Arrokoth flyby data?
What are "large hadrons"? Are there also "small hadrons"?
Did it take 3 minutes to reload a musket when the second amendment to the US constitution was ratified?
Are tech workers in the Siberian city of Tomsk really "descendants of those sent to the gulags"?

I'm not questioning that an occasional question that calls into question something that's been written is OK, and no question about it; I ask those potentially questionable questions myself!
It's just that if we make a tag for "debunking" here in Astronomy SE, then it seems to me to invite a much higher rate of relatively low-quality questions here in Astronomy SE with little short-term OR long-term value from their answers.
Real debunking is usually asked in Skeptics SE and they can be on any topic - including Astronomy.

I agree.  Real debunking goes to skeptics.  Bad, low quality debunking goes in the garbage. hence no need for the tag here.

Would a misconception tag be better

I don’t see how my question was low quality as my main concern is not with the word always but rather with the premise that shower meteors come in bursts

@Harrychink Sorry! I didn't mean to imply that your question was low quality, only that the existence of the tag may make some question-askers feel that it semi-legitimizes their question about any possible editorial error in any popular astronomy website or blog.

Great call going to Meta with this and not engaging in tit-for-tat.  It would be hard to justify closing flat earth nonsense, all the UFO stuff and every other crackpot theory if all the poster had to do was tag it "debunk".

I do not think we need a 'debunk' tag.
From Meriam-Webster, to debunk is: "to expose the sham or falseness of". I think a 'debunk' tab is unnecessarily presumptuous and perhaps a bit derogatory. Many of us wouldn't take it well if we were told one of our ideas was 'bunk' without an authoritative citation. If a belief or widely held position is actually a sham, then a well-posed question should expose it without such a tag.
If we believe in Astronomy Stack Exchange, the answers and votes should sort it out. If you think someone is trying to sell snake-oil like flat-earth, take it to the Skeptics SE.
If we reach a consensus on this question, I'll help implement it.

My initial reaction to reading this question is exactly this answer: no. I'm not an astronomer by any stretch of the word, but I can see a "debunk" tag being a challenge to the community to provide evidence that someone's false beliefs are false when the OP believes them to be true. I think that plays to the derogatory tone of the word "debunk." --- "The earth is flat. I am right because (non-scientific) A, B and C. Prove I am wrong, and I will be the judge of whether you are right by withholding the green checkmark since I am not convinced!"
